# audio autoplay not working html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

Something really akward is happening in my code, the autoplay for audio is not working.

Basically, every website code that i put this code the music autoplays but in this one is not working.

Find the footer code:

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <h1>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/topoPirelli.png" alt=""></a>
        </h1>
    </ul>
    <audio class="audio" loop autoplay="autoplay" controls>
        <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the files (1.ogg, 1.mp3) exist ?

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: No erros! wich makes this pretty weird

Comment: YEs they do, and when i press play it does work. The only thing that is not working is teh autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by using jquery in the end:

```
$('audio').on('canplay', function() {
    this.play();
});
```

**Edit:**
Nowadays I noticed a lot of browsers don't allow autoplay to work if the video sound. So a solution could be adding the `muted` attribute.

```
<video autoplay muted>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<audio class="audio" controls autoplay>
  <source src="./1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="./1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 <!-- <embed height="50" width="100" src="./1.mp3"> NOT NECESSARY -->
</audio>
```