# Audio Tag HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I make a web app with HTML,CSS & JS.

I parse a xml with url's with any songs, and i mount a player with this songs.

I make this code for JS to change the song:

```
var newSongHtml = '<div class="navbar-header" id="playersongs">';
  newSongHtml += ' <h3>' + nombreChannelActual + ' - ' + categoriaActual + '</h3>';
  newSongHtml += '<div class="audio-player">';
  newSongHtml += ' <h2>' + currentSongName + '</h2>';
  newSongHtml += '<audio id="audio-player" src="' + currentSong + '" type="audio/mp3" ontimeupdate="onTimeUpdateCurrentSong(\'' + currentPlayList + '\')" onended="changeCurrentSong(\'' + currentPlayList + '\');" onerror="checkErrorWhenWillPlaySong(\'' + currentPlayList + '\')" controls="controls"></audio>';
  newSongHtml += '</div>';
  newSongHtml += '</div>';

  $('#playersongs').replaceWith(newSongHtml);

  $('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
      alwaysShowControls: true,
      features: ['playpause','progress','currenttime','duration'],
      audioWidth: 450,
      audioHeight: 40,
      iPadUseNativeControls: false,
      iPhoneUseNativeControls: false,
      AndroidUseNativeControls: false
  });`
```

My problem is: 
When I'm playing a long time and have changed several songs. The player stopped, crashed, the player don't run, enter in state stopped forever, no matter what I do.
I have seen with the developer tools that there is a folder called media , where files are stored PART_32435435.mp3

I think it may be so , because the console does not tell me any errors

Is it possible that this is the problem? How could I do to delete it?

Comment: volume goes down? moves down? What is going down?

Comment: enter in state stopped forever. Without an error of JS

Comment: forgive me I explained very bad

Comment: No, its fine, I am just trying to understand. Can you repeat this in a jsfiddle or plnkr? Are you sure you aren't changing songs to an undefined source?

Comment: Audio src is an mp3 url that is hosted in another site, i'm sure that this source is exist, because i'm save the index of my playlist in cache an when i reload page the audio begin with this song and it's play

Comment: In which browser is this, or does it happen in several browsers?

Comment: in chroome this happens when it's have play 7 songs. In firefox and safari happens but with more songs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because there is a single quote in the song name? That might break the script where you have `src="' + currentSong + '"` unless it is escaped somewhere. I tested this with the second song containing a single quote in the filename and it works...

```
<div id="playersongs"></div>
<script>
var nombreChannelActual = "nombreChannelActual";
var categoriaActual = "categoriaActual";
var currentPlayList = ["Michael Jackson - Remember The Time.mp3","Michael Jackson - Can't Let Her Get Away.mp3","Michael Jackson - Dangerous.mp3"];
var currentSongName = currentPlayList[0].split('.')[0];
var currentSong = currentPlayList[0];

function onTimeUpdateCurrentSong(a){
//console.log("!");
}

function canplay(){
//play when buffered enough to begin
$('audio').on('canplay', function() {
    this.play();
});
}

function changeCurrentSong(){
var current_song = $('#audio-player').attr("src");
var current_song_position = currentPlayList.indexOf(current_song);
if(current_song_position == currentPlayList.length-1){
    //it has reached the end, go back to first song
    $('#audio-player').attr("src",currentPlayList[0]);
    $('#current_song_name').html(currentPlayList[0].split('.')[0]);
    canplay();
}
else {
    //play next song
    $('#audio-player').attr("src",currentPlayList[current_song_position+1]);
    $('#current_song_name').html(currentPlayList[current_song_position+1].split('.')[0]);
    canplay();
}
}

var newSongHtml = '<div class="navbar-header" id="playersongs">';
newSongHtml += ' <h3>' + nombreChannelActual + ' - ' + categoriaActual + '</h3>';
newSongHtml += '<div class="audio-player">';
newSongHtml += " <h2 id='current_song_name'>" + currentSongName + "</h2>";
newSongHtml += "<audio id='audio-player' src='" + currentSong + "' type='audio/mp3' onended='changeCurrentSong();' controls='controls' autoplay></audio>";
newSongHtml += '</div>';
newSongHtml += '</div>';

$('#playersongs').replaceWith(newSongHtml);

</script>
```

Comment: this is a very viable answer. I am curios if this fixes OPs problem

Comment: Ohh yeah!! you're the best!! This code fix this problem. I was replace the audio tag always, and now i only replace this one time. But has come new problem, i set this tag:  <audio autoplay ....></audio>   and the autoplay only works in the first play, when i change the current song with new method this not autoplay.

Comment: Do you know, Why it can be happening?

Comment: I tested this with files locally in IE/FF/Chrome and couldn't see any issues. If the next song plays when you click play maybe it is a buffering issue? If that is the case you can use jquery to start on canplay event like in the comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249515/audio-autoplay-not-working-html5